# Order by MYSQL dynamic clause. Using $_REQUEST

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a $_REQUEST variable jump menu on my page allowing people to change the ASC or DESC order by post_time.

The problem is getting the default to DESC order and having it work without changing the URL $_REQUEST variable.

Here is what I have:

jump menu:

```
<form name="form" id="form">

<select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
<option value ="?post_time=DESC" 
 <?php echo ($_REQUEST['post_time']=='DESC')?"selected":"";?> >DESC</option>
<option value ="?post_time=ASC" 
<?php echo ($_REQUEST['post_time']=='ASC')?"selected":"";?> >ASC</option>  
</select>

</form>
```

Order by clause:

```
ORDER BY post_time {$_REQUEST['post_time']}
```

Like I said, it works great if you open the page, but it defaults at ASC, I tried to set the variable to = "DESC" at the top and it works, but then it won't change to ASC.

Any quick ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<form name="form" id="form">

<select name="post_time" id="jumpMenu" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
<option value ="DESC" 
 <?php if(($_REQUEST['post_time']=='DESC')||(!isset($_REQUEST['post_time']))){echo"'selected'";}?> >DESC</option>
<option value ="ASC" 
<?php if($_REQUEST['post_time']=='ASC'){echo"'selected'";}?> >ASC</option>  
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: So it sets to desc if it is selected previously, or if nothing has been previously selected (default). Note also that I've slightly adjusted the form so it will work correcly with both post and get, as well as should any other fields be added before/after the select

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<option value ="DESC" 
 <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['post_time']) && $_REQUEST['post_time']=='DESC') { print " selected=\"selected\"";}?> >DESC</option>
<option value ="ASC" 
 <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['post_time']) && $_REQUEST['post_time']=='ASC') { print " selected=\"selected\"";}?> >ASC</option>
```

I also wouldn't advise you doing this:

ORDER BY post_time {$_REQUEST['post_time']}

Try:

```
$order = 'ASC'; // Default

// Check for DESC as ASC is the default
if(isset($_REQUEST['post_time']) && $_REQUEST['post_time'] == 'DESC') {
   $order = 'DESC';
}

ORDER BY post_time {$order}
```

I think this page shows a good example of what you're trying to accomplish:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: I used this [code]
if(isset($_REQUEST['post_time']) && $_REQUEST['post_time'] == 'ASC') {
   $order = 'ASC';
}
else {
 $order = 'DESC';
 } [/code]
But, when I change the jump menu to ASC, it jumps back to DESC???

Answer (score 0):

Never ever use $_REQUEST. It's a bed practice. And

> ORDER BY post_time {$_REQUEST['post_time']}

is not very nice either. Don't forget escape all user entered data with mysql_real_escape_string.

2 previous advices are quite good, have nothing to add